# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' for Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic5

I have Ionic version 5 and using cordova. I am running `ionic cordova run android` and getting following error:

```
> Configure project :app
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\authenticator.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka io.ionic.starter:mipmap/icon) not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
16 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 15 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

It looks like gradle issue. I googled but did not find proper answer. Could you please help?